# PHP website page loading is very slow in localhost

Tags: html, php, css, ajax

PHP website pages are taking very long time to load for **huge data** in localhost(using Xampp). The page loading becomes faster for less data. Could anyone tell why how this can be?

Answer (score 1):

I would say if your computer processing power is good enough then you need to look at your implementation.

If you got massive data to process and load then you might have to consider following:

- Find ways to improve your code and minimise unnecessary code execution.
- If your code is fine then you might have to look at your database and find ways to improve and here there are so many things involved like: database cleanup, indexing etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problem to process large data first and foremost you should optimize your code such as loops and multiple variables.

And also you can use caching provide by php such as [php apc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or other accelerators mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators) as per your comfort.